# Hyperledger fabric - Uploaded wrong set of transactions. Want these to be excluded in chaincode queries

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, immutability, blockchain

We have set up a hyperledger fabric network and uploaded a history of transactions. Realized that part of these transactions are incorrect and hence we want to exclude them from chaincode queries.

From whatever I understand, the shim API DelState can be used to delete an asset from World state and hence this will not appear in chaincode queries.

But, we do not want to delete the entire asset. We just want to mark few transactions as invalid.

Comment: could you elaborate on how do you store those transactions and what exactly do you mean by asset?

Comment: Each transaction is stored as a json i.e. it has few key-value pairs.

Comment: @ArtemBarger - Each transaction is stored as a json.
By asset, I mean a 'key' in the Blockchain ledger. The history of transactions for each 'key' is stored in the Blockchain ledger and the last transaction is stored in the State DB.
Shim API DelState can be used to delete a 'key' entirely.

Reference:
[link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/chaincode/shim/mockstub.go#L257) 
[link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/readwrite.html)